# Conditional If Statement Syntax in Batch

Tags: batch-file, if-statement, syntax, conditional-statements

I have checked several resources on conditional if statement syntax for batch scripts, and despite this, I'm unable to find my mistake. I typically avoid asking questions here that should be this simple, but it's the last task on a huge project so I'm hoping someone can help me see what I'm doing wrong. This is a script for a university project, and is merely for an exploration of concepts.

```
@Echo OFF

REM Check time remaining
for /f "tokens=3 delims=: " %%a in (
'cscript //nologo "%systemroot%\system32\slmgr.vbs" /dli ^| find "Time remaining: "' 
) do set "timeRemainingStatus=%%a"

Echo %timeRemainingStatus%
pause

REM Check SkipRearm dword value
setlocal ENABLEEXTENSIONS
set KEY_NAME="HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\SoftwareProtectionPlatform"
set VALUE_NAME=SkipRearm

FOR /F "usebackq skip=2 tokens=1-3" %%A IN (`REG QUERY %KEY_NAME% /v %VALUE_NAME% 2^>nul`) DO (
set ValueName=%%A
set ValueType=%%B
set ValueValue=%%C
)

Echo Value Name: %ValueName%
Echo Value Value: %ValueValue%
pause

IF %timeRemainingStatus% EQU 20160 (
Echo First level
pause
IF defined ValueName (
    Echo Second Level
    pause
    IF %ValueValue% == "0x0" (
        Echo Third Level
        pause
        regedit.exe /s "C:\Windows\SR.reg"
    )
) ELSE (
    Echo Fourth Level
    pause
    SLMGR /REARM
    )
)
pause
```

I have the echos and pauses in there so I can see what code runs and to verify that the variables are retaining their values. It crashes for me after the second pause (after the Echo Value Value: %ValueValue% command). I assume it's something wrong with syntax, but I've been unable to see any errors because the command prompt closes, despite all the pauses I have.

Comment: Have you tried changing it to the following? `IF "x%timeRemainingStatus%"=="x20160"`

Comment: Thanks for the response. What does the x do? If I'm understanding the rest of your suggestion properly, you're recommending I do string comparison instead of integer comparison? It may be possible that in the future this script would have to check for values equal to or less than 0, and I'm not sure how I'd do such a thing with string comparison.

Comment: The x is there to have a safe character. When doing string comparison I would always recommending to do it his way. If you would have a `?` in there this might crash your script. If you need the integer comparison I would suggest doing this before your if-statement `set /a timeRemainingStatus=%timeRemainingStatus%` which if you know Java works like a parse to integer so it can be used as that. If you do not get any error messages, hold shift and rightclick in your batch-file directory and click "open command-window here" (smth like that) and type the name of your file. The window wont close.

Comment: The `x` is completely useless in case you have quoted comparison values; (an) extra character(s) is/are used to avoid empty values, which would cause the `if` clause to fail; if there are quotes, they are literally part of the comparison, hence nothing appears empty to `if`; the quotes have the additional advantage that _spaces_ in the strings to compare do no longer harm. In case you have _integers_ to compare, do not use quotes (or any other extra characters), and use the comparison operators `EQU`, `NEQ`, etc., instead of `==`, because they do numeric comparisons if integers are provided...

Answer (score 0):

When setting variables within for loops or if statements, you'll need to take advantage of `Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion`. This also applies when referencing variables set in this context. Any variables that use EnableDelayedExpansion will need to have exclamation points around the variable instead of percentages (`!Value!` instead of `%Value%`). You'll need to change your code to take advantage of this.

Answer (score 0):

There were a few things wrong. This is the solution I went with:

```
@Echo OFF

REM Check time remaining
for /f "tokens=3 delims=: " %%a in (
'cscript //nologo "%systemroot%\system32\slmgr.vbs" /dli ^| find "Time remaining: "' 
) do set /a "timeRemainingStatus=%%a"

setlocal ENABLEEXTENSIONS
set KEY_NAME="HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\SoftwareProtectionPlatform"
set VALUE_NAME=SkipRearm

FOR /F "usebackq skip=2 tokens=1-3" %%A IN (`REG QUERY %KEY_NAME% /v %VALUE_NAME% 2^>nul`) DO (
set ValueName=%%A
set ValueType=%%B
set ValueValue=%%C
)

IF %timeRemainingStatus% EQU 0 (
    IF defined ValueName (
        IF "%ValueValue%" == "0x0" (
            regedit.exe /s "C:\Windows\SR.reg"
        )
        IF "%ValueValue%" == "0x1" (
            SLMGR /REARM
        )
    )
)
```

I needed to add /a to set (which I thought I had before, but I guess not). Additionally, I forgot quotes when comparing %ValueValue% to "0x0". While it may not be the cleanest way of doing things, I also changed the if-else into two if statements.

I've tested this at startup on a VM and it appears to be working properly. Much appreciated to the help given.